# Can an image in html not overlap a bootstrap-column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

After quite a while I was able to fix a problem that was bugging me. I would love someone to explain the solution to my though, because I don't understand why it works, and the way I usually do it did not this time.

My goal was the put an image into a h3-tag (design reasons), and then let the iamge overlap with the div underneath. Normally, I would use margin-bottom: -30px; to move the image down. It did not work this time though.
I figured that when I try to overlap a boots-trap-column that contains a div with a background, it does not work (the images "hides" behind the div with the background). Only giving the .col-xs-8 a z-index: -1; worked (but giving a z-index: 9999; to the image did not).

Could someone please explain to me why? Or are there any bootstrap fundamentals I am not aware of?

Any help or input is appreciated. Thanks! :)

Here was the project code I was working on (HTML):

```
<div>
    <h3>
        <img src="assets/test.png" class="test-img">
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="wrapper">
            A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text! A lot of text!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.wrapper {
background: url(/assets/back.png);
width: 250px;
}

.col-xs-8 {
//z-index: -1;
}

.test-img {
//margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

Comment: "z-index only works on ___ elements" - go do some basic research, and fill in the blank.

Comment: Okay, well that was easy. "Positioned"! :P
Thanks @CBroe!
Instead of  comparing my working projects with my not working code (and not seeing the 'position: relative; down in the style-sheet-nirvana', I could have just googled z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class "position:relative;" to the image, because z-index only works on positioned elements.